# Preventing a randomly generated picture from appearing twice in a row

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a picturebox ("piturebox1") and an imagelist ("imagelist1") with four pictures. I want these to change randomly every 2 seconds and I don't want the same picture to appear twice in a row.

My current code is:

```
    Dim Pic As Integer

    Dim rand As New Random

    Pic = rand.Next(0, ImageList1.Images.Count)

    PictureBox1.Image = ImageList1.Images(Pic)
```

Comment: "Random" includes the possibility that the image comes twice in a row. Even more often. Maybe what you really want is a shuffled list?

Comment: You should include your code. Sounds like you'll have to do a check for what the current picture is though before changing to the next

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour]. You will need to do some research and try something yourself; this is not a code writing service or tutorial site/

Comment: Use a timer.  Do not initialize Random more than once.  Do not use ImageList, always favor List(Of Image).  Google "vb.net random shuffle" to get somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only have four pictures, while shuffling instead of randomly selecting is usually the preferred solution for such problems it is not going to do you much good if you want to show the pictures for more than 8 seconds. In this particular case, you might be better off just keep selecting random pictures that are not the current one:

```
' do not repeat this part....
Dim Pic As Integer = -1, LastSelected As Integer = -1
Dim rand As New Random



While Pic = LastSelected
    Pic = rand.Next(0, ImageList1.Images.Count)
Loop

PictureBox1.Image = ImageList1.Images(Pic)
' Wait for 2 seconds, rinse, repeat
```